# Как правильно отловить event в react/typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Есть метод, который меняет имя у добавленного объекта

```
const onChangeName = (title: any, id: number) => {
    const car = cars[id]
    car.title = title
    const changedCar = [...cars]
    changedCar[id] = car
    setCars(changedCar)
}
```

сразу при input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="change name"
    onChange={() => onChange(car.title, car.id)} value={car.title}/>
```

хочу отловить event, но TypeScript выдаёт ошибку (пишет, что не может поменять title у undefined). На обычном React без ts всё работает.

```
<CarList
    cars={cars}
    onRemove={removeHandler}
    /*onChange={onChangeName}*/
    onChangeName={event => onChangeName(event.target.value, id)}
/>
```

UPD: Всё-таки динамически удалось поменять title таким образом

```
const onChangeName = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    cars.map(car => {
        car.title = event.target.value
        return (
            console.log(car.title)
        )
    })
}
```

Но при этом меняется только 1 элемент, и то только в консоли. То есть, если title был "test", а мы дописали "123" , то он измениться только на "test1".

Comment: какая ошибка-то?

Comment: @Grundy пишет, что не может поменять title у undefined

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play и https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-water-dnxkz , попробуйте

Comment: это пишет при сборке тайпскрипт или это рантайм ошибка в браузере?

Comment: @Grundy рантайм ошибка, когда я пытаюсь поменять title

Comment: выведи cars, и id, и проверь что действительно есть такой элемент, который ты хочешь получить

Comment: @Grundy такой элемент есть. До этого такая же логика была написана на чистом реакте
 onChangeName(name, index) {
        const car = this.state.cars[index]
        car.name = name
        const cars = [...this.state.cars]
        cars[index] = car
        this.setState({cars})
    } 
рендер :<Car  onChangeName={event => this.onChangeName(event.target.value, index)} />

Тут всё работало. Я просто хочу перенести эту логику в react+ts..

Comment: ты пробовала вывести то что я просил?

Comment: пока, так как у тебя отличается код на ts и js - странно, почему они должны одинаково работать. Приведи два конкретных примера в вопросе: как это сделано на "чистом" реакте и работает и как это сделано на тайпскрипте. Только пример должны быть такие, чтобы можно было их сравнить между собой, а не как у тебя обычно, что в одном примере одна часть, во втором совсем другая

Comment: `const car = cars[id]; if (null == car) { console.log({ cars, id }); debugger; }`

Comment: car = car1, id = 1579519175849  (id это Date.now()) если пишу const car = { ...cars[id], title } вместо const car = cars[id] . А так car = undefined

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> onChange={onChangeName}
> ```

Тут скорее всего 1 аргумент, причём `event`. Сравниваем с

> ```
> const onChangeName = (title: any, id: number) => {
> ```

Очевидно, сигнатура не сходится. `event` под `any` прокатит (хотя получится фигня), а второго аргумента просто нет и он явно не подходит.

---

И не по теме:

> ```
> const car = cars[id]
> ```

Тут ошибка. Должно быть

```
const car = { ...cars[id] }
```

Впрочем, можно сразу объединить со следующей строчкой и сделать так:

```
const car = { ...cars[id], title }
```

Comment: согласна, но 2 аргумент id нужен нам в самой логике onChangeName,чтобы поменять имя у конкретной машины.. Как тогда к event.target обратиться?

Comment: вы это имеете ввиду?
 const onChangeName = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {setTitle(event.target.value)  }

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, вы игнорируете основу React - Virtual Dom, как следствие, не пользуетесь состояниями, а сами объекты изменяете в обход реакта без `setState`. Какой смысл во всем этом? Погадать на "косточках", какие у вас могут быть ошибки в коде, которого мы не видим?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="change name" onChange={() => onChange(car.title,car.id)} value={car.title}/>
```

> In React, mutable state is typically kept in the state property of components, and only updated with setState()

Это, конечно, не супер критично, но что у вас дальше "под капотом"?

```
const onChangeName = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        cars.map(car => {
            car.title = event.target.value
            return (
                console.log(car.title)
            )
        })
    }
```

Не ясно, как бедняга `map` должен работать, если

> array.map(callback[, thisObject]);
>
> map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

Вы же возвращаете:

```
return ( console.log(car.title))
```

Вам нужно начать использовать `state` и менять атрибуты (хотя бы автомобиля) через `setState`, т.к. сейчас вообще не понятно, чем вам можно помочь.

Сюда смотреть по стейтам
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Сюда по формам в реакт
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Задан ли у вас тип для `cars`? Какое точно сообщение даёт TS?

Чтобы TS не говорил, что не может поменять `title` у `undefined`, нужно, чтобы он знал, что у `car` тип, имеющий поле `title` (`any` тут не годится: `any` может быть `undefined`, на что он, вероятно, и ругается – если тип для `cars` не задан – а для `car` он не задан явно, это видно по коду).

Простейшее, что можно попробовать – написать

```
const car: { title: string, [key]: any } = cars[id]
```

но лучше, конечно, создать тип `car` и использовать его, где надо (в частности, `cars` должен быть типа `car[]` и тип переменной `car` TS тогда выведет сам, хотя можно написать явно `const car: car = cars[id]`).

Comment: TS никогда не ругается, что any может быть undefined.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен, но точная ошибка нам так и не была предоставлена